# как вывести топ 3 значения словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x, dict

есть словарь. нужно распечатать из него топ 3 по значению,
ну и ещё 3 минимальных.

```
    for key, value in sorted_ticker_dict.items():
        print(f'{" " * 2}{key[7:18]} - {value}%')
```

содержимое:

```
  TICKER_SiH9 - 24.39%
  TICKER_PDM9 - 23.20%
  TICKER_PDH9 - 22.69%
  TICKER_MNH9 - 20.68%
  TICKER_BRH9 - 19.49%
  TICKER_BRJ9 - 18.89%
  TICKER_CHH9 - 18.01%
  TICKER_BRK9 - 17.57%
  TICKER_SRM9 - 17.43%
```

даже не представляю как это сделать

Comment: А не проще вместо `{" " * 2}` просто два пробелам в строку записать? :) `print(f'  {key[7:18]} - {value}%')`

Comment: мне дальше нужно их будет больше. не буду же я, скажем, 20 пробелов нажимать...)

Comment: Понятно, логично :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

первые три

```
for key, value in list(sorted_ticker_dict.items())[:3]:
```

и последние три

```
for key, value in list(sorted_ticker_dict.items())[-3:]:
```

Comment: а что, так можно было?) благодарю!

Comment: можно :) только в список преобразовать надо